# How compile C# on Ubuntu editing in Emacs?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, emacs, compilation

I want to use Emacs on my Linux system (Ubuntu Distro) to write and compile C# - Code. (For learning purposes, pretty basic stuff only.)

**Is there a way to write, compile and execute C# code on Ubuntu using Emacs as an editor?**

I'm a little confused by what to do, as the [CSharpMode](http://www.emacswiki.org/CSharpMode) - Explanation on the EmacsWiki seems to be for compiling on Windows.

Also, I'm aware that Emacs itself can't compile. Where should I look for a suitable compiler?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thank you for letting me know. What compiler should I use? Is there a way to run the compiler from within Emacs, similar to how it is shown on the Emacs Wiki (link in question).

Comment: C# on Linux ?  Install Windows in a VM and install VS ?  Beyond that I haven't a clue.  But I imagine it's a question your favourite search engine can help you answer for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compile C# code under Emacs you can run the command

```
(compile "xbuild MySolution.sln")
```

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/xbuild/

If you want code completion and intellisense-like features, have a look at omnisharp

https://github.com/nosami/Omnisharp
https://github.com/sp3ctum/omnisharp-emacs

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/]) for your compiling needs, and perhaps figure out how to integrate it into the Emacs Mode. I suggest though, to make things easier, you try a real IDE built for the task, such as [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/).